# NetworkImageView crashing

Tags: android, listview, networkimageview

My app has an activity with a `ListView`, and for each cell in the list, I need to load an image from an URL. However, the app crashes when I add the line to load the image.

I don't know if the error is caused by my code or some cell-reuse-behavior of the List View, since the Logcat does not point to any line in my code.
I made sure that the URLs passed are correct and may not interfere.

I followed [this tutorial](https://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/category/android/volley/networkimageview/) to write this code.

Here's the `ListView` adapter class, where I load the imagem on `getView(...)`:

```
class CellAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    List<Product> productList;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public CellAdapter(Context context, List<Product> productList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productList = productList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Product getItem(int position) {
        return productList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        while (view == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_result, null);

        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cell_product_image);
        image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.image_placeholder);
        image.setImageUrl(getItem(position).imageURL, APIManager.getSharedImageLoader());

        return view;
    }
}
```

The `ImageLoader` used above is set up as follows:

```
sharedImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(context), new BitmapLruCache());
```

And the `BitmapLruCache` is:

```
public class BitmapLruCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageLoader.ImageCache {

    public BitmapLruCache() {
        this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());
    }

    public BitmapLruCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
        super(sizeInKiloBytes);
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
        return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        return get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
        put(url, bitmap);
    }

    public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
        final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

        return maxMemory / 8;
    }
}
```

This is the Logcat error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android.volley.Request.<init>(Request.java:137)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest.<init>(ImageRequest.java:71)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader.get(ImageLoader.java:219)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.loadImageIfNecessary(NetworkImageView.java:149)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView.onLayout(NetworkImageView.java:198)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1833)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1748)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1262)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:343)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:343)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:343)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3714)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:853)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the method containing the null pointer exception:

```
    public Request(int method, String url, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        mMethod = method;
        mUrl = url;
        mErrorListener = listener;
        setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy());
        /* the next line is line 137 with the Exception */
        mDefaultTrafficStatsTag = TextUtils.isEmpty(url) ? 0: Uri.parse(url).getHost().hashCode(); 
    }
```

Comment: can you share APIManager.getSharedImageLoader() code?

Comment: It just returns the static variable `sharedImageLoader` I write above.

Comment: But how you are passing context to 
sharedImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(context), new BitmapLruCache());

Comment: The `APIManager` class will `getApplicationContext()` and use it.

Comment: You have a null pointer exception on line 137 of Request.java, however the version of code you are using does not appear to be the current version from git (line 137 of which is unlikely to result in this exception), so you will need to provide the version you are using.  You may want to see if there are known issues with the library or report your problem to the author.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: http://pastebin.com/nZrABGpK

Comment: Either `Uri.parse(url)` returns null, or else `Uri.parse(url).getHost()` does.  Note that this code is not in the current version of the library, so perhaps it has been changed

Comment: @ChrisStratton I added `com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:+@jar` as a dependency in my build.gradle file. Do you think I should clone the library and add it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an out-of-date version of this library, which is missing the following two recent commits:

> 6c33917  Merge "Guard against NullPointerException currently occurring
>   in Volley when a Request is given a url whose host is null." by Ficus
>   Kirkpatrick - 3 weeks ago idea133-weekly-release master
>
> 0ec9297  Guard against NullPointerException currently occurring in
>   Volley when a Request is given a url whose host is null. by kang - 3
>   weeks ago

Update your working version with git to reflect the current state of the project repository and you should be fine.  Examining the diff for these, the change is basically adding and handling null checking.